# C++ What should we pass in MurmurHash3 parameters?

Tags: c++, hash, murmurhash

I am confused with what parameter should I provide for the MurmurHash3_x86_128(). The murmurhash3 code can be found https://github.com/aappleby/smhasher/blob/master/src/MurmurHash3.cpp. Method definition is given below.

```
void MurmurHash3_x86_128 ( const void * key, const int len,
                       uint32_t seed, void * out )
```

I have passed the following values in the above method but my compiler is giving me segmentation fault. What am i doing wrong ?

```
int main()
{
    uint64_t seed = 1;
    uint64_t *hash_otpt;
    const char *key = "hi";
    MurmurHash3_x64_128(key, (uint64_t)strlen(key), seed, hash_otpt);
    cout << "hashed" << hash_otpt << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: At least you should allocate memory for `hash_otpt`. Currently you are passing invalid pointer to the function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This function put its hash in 128 bits of memory.

What your are doing is passing a pointer, that is not allocated yet to it.

The correct usage would be something like that:

```
int main()
{
   uint64_t seed = 1;
   uint64_t hash_otpt[2];  // allocate 128 bits
   const char *key = "hi";
   MurmurHash3_x64_128(key, (uint64_t)strlen(key), seed, hash_otpt);
   cout << "hashed" << hash_otpt[0] << hash_otpt[1] << endl;
   return 0;
 }
```

You could have noticed that by analyzing how `MurmurHash3_x86_128` fills `out` parameter:

```
((uint64_t*)out)[0] = h1;
((uint64_t*)out)[1] = h2;
```

Comment: does it means that the output is split into 2 incase  MurmurHash3_x64_128 and split into four in MurmurHash3_x86_128? did i get that right?

Answer (score 1):

`hash_otpt` is a pointer to nothing, but the function expects the fourth argument to be a pointer *to some memory* as it writes its output into this memory. In your example, it attempts a write operation, but fails (*there's nowhere to write to* as the pointer is not initialized). This gives you a SegmentationFault.

Figure out in how many `uint64_t`s does the hash fit into (2, because the output's size is 128 bits, and the size of a `uint64_t` is 64 bits) and allocate the memory:

```
hash_otpt = new uint64_t [2];
```

Comment: Or better `const size_t needed_size=2; uint64_t hash_otpt[needed_size];`  (The constant 2 found by inspecting the source.)

Comment: We also need to clarify what should `len` be. Does it tell length of `key` (it declared as pointrer to `void`, not `char`, so it doesn't look like function wants C string) or `out`? Impossible to tell without that specific lib knowledge

Answer (score 0):

If you look at [the documentation](https://github.com/PeterScott/murmur3), you can see

> **MurmurHash3_x64_128** ... It has a 128-bit output.

So, your code can be something like this

```
    uint64_t hash_otpt[2]; // This is 128 bits
    MurmurHash3_x64_128(key, (uint64_t)strlen(key), seed, hash_otpt);
```

Note that you don't have to dynamically allocate the output at all.